# Can a member group upload a file in an entry, but not access File Manager?

Tags: members, file-manager

I have a member group where a member can only edit their own entries. Their entry contains a File field. I thought if I went to the Upload Directory preferences and select their group to access this Upload Directory, it would be fine. But when trying to upload, they get the error, "You are not authorized to perform this action."

Going into the Member Group settings and allowing them access to File Manager fixed this. But I'd rather they not have access to the File Manager (lots more than they need). Any ideas on how to let them upload a file, but NOT access the File Manager? (Or am I doing something wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm hiding the link to "Files" in the CP. Done by:

Go to /www/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/View/_shared/header.php, search for 'icon-files', then the line above that, change

```
<?php if (ee()->cp->allowed_group('can_access_files'): ?>
```

to

```
<?php if (ee()->cp->allowed_group('can_access_files') && ee()->session->userdata('group_id') !== 6): ?>
```

Where 6 is the member group. I'd rather not have to do this every time I update EE, so I'm still hoping I'm doing something wrong, or this is a bug that will be eventually fixed.